# rxjs behavior subject set value from component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have a service A, this service holds an rxjs behaviorsubject:

```
public publishedList:BehaviorSubject<Data> = new BehaviorSubject<Data>(null)

getlist():Observable<Data> {
return this.http.post(......).map((responseData) => {
 this.publishedList.next(responseData)
 this.publishedList.asObservable().share
 }
}
```

Component A listens to this behaviorsubject using subscribe in the constructor.
No issues here.

Now component B comes in to place and holds a button that should be able to clear or empty the publishedList in the service and Component A should be updated.

Is this possible? How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

add this method to your service

```
setList(data:Data) {
  this.publishedList.next(data);
}
```

and call it from component B

Comment: Thank you. It works.
I don't need the this.publishedList.asObservable().share ?
Can you explain why?

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service shows how to use observables. It's common to not expose a subject directly (as `public`), but `this.publishedList.asObservable().share` should be in the constructor of your service and you should assign it to a different variable (for example with a `$` suffix. `share` doesn't have much of an effect if you only have a single subscriber.